# Adding an "ADD TO CART" button to a collection

Tags: shopify

I have a client asking to add an "ADD TO CART" button under each product in their collections and I can't figure out how.
I'm new to the Shopify platform and I am not familiar with Liquid but I did try to use the built in "Channel" of adding a Buy Button, but when trying to paste in the code it didn't populate anything in the preview page.
Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: I build this free app to deal with this https://apps.shopify.com/instant-add-to-cart. It's automatic, no coding required.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shopify API by adding this into the `collection.liquid`

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variant.id }}" />
 <input min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Add that somewhere in this loop

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

`product.variant.id` identifies which item is added to the cart and it could be replaced with `product.variants.first.id`

This details how it works and applies to standard, non ajax, forms too
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#add-to-cart

Comment: @RyanMilton please accept the answer if this worked for you thanks!